# Where can one access the electrical buses in an aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, electrical-system, airframe-and-powerplant

I am looking at how new systems are retrofitted in aircrafts (**large business jets or airliners**), and I was wondering where the mechanics can get access to electrical power.

More specifically, I know that there is an electrical cabinet close to the cockpit, but are there any accessible AC buses elsewhere in the aircraft (for example, so that you don't have to run wires all the way back if you install something near the empennage)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which aircraft?

Comment: General question for large biz jets and airliners. But for a start, info on the Challenger 605 or Gulfstream G550 would be very helpful

Comment: You want the fuses accessible to the pilot, so you are going to have to run a wire for the equipment up to the fuse panel in the cockpit anyway. Usually this is where you pick up off the AC or DC buss and add the appropriate fuse, then run the wires to the equipment.

Comment: The Challenger 605 electrical systems description is available from SmartCockpit [here](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/CL605-ELECTRICAL.html).